# combinatorics - division of objects

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways is it possible to divide 50 identical apples and 50 identical oranges to 60 identical baskets?

I know how to do it when the baskets are different, but when they are identical I have know clue. Maybe divide the possibilities by $60!$ ?

Comment: Yes, you divide by $60!$ to get rid of unidentical baskets.

Comment: Your intuition is solid here! Consider this simple example. How many ways can you put the numbers $\{1,2,3\}$ into three different baskets, with one number in each basket? There are $3!$ different ways to do it. Now, how many ways can you put each number in any basket? Well, as long as a number is in a basket it's all the same, so there's only one way to do it.

Comment: This discussion is heading wrong! you cannot divide by $60!$ simply. wait for ~10-15 min and I am describing how.

Comment: The problem has too many possible interpretations to me. Can you cut the apples and oranges? What does identical basket mean; they all have to be filled with exactly the same contents, or the same number of fruits, or they all have the same capacity? The problem is not clear to me.

Comment: @Arby Identical baskets mean that you cannot differenciate them just by looking them i.e. they have no unique identity.Same is the case with apples and oranges.